# After Uploading html files its broken images

Tags: html, css, web, error-handling

I made an html file that is working fine but after uploading it to some free domain host some images are not loaded. [This](http://dextersilva.epizy.com/?i=1) is the website and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuVDF.png) is what its supposed to look like

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body id="grad1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenav.css">
<div class="nav" align="right"><font size="4%"><!--NAV BAR-->
    <nav>
            <font size="3%"><a href="main.html" title="Home" class="navb" target="bottom" id="navb1"><b><img src="icons/home.png" height="30%" width="30%" class="invert"></b></a></font>
            <font size="3%"><a href="about.html" class="navb" target="bottom" id="navb2"><b><img src="icons/about.png" height="30%" width="30%" title="About" class="invert"></b></a></font>
            <font size="3%"><a href="gallery.html" class="navb" target="bottom" id="navb3"><b><img src="icons/gallery.png" height="30%" width="30%" title="Gallery" class="invert"></b></a></font>
            <font size="3%"><a href="favorites.html" class="navb" target="bottom" id="navb4"><b><img src="icons/favorites.png" height="30%" width="30%" title="Favorites" class="invert"></b></a></font>
            <font size="3%"><a href="hobbies.html" class="navb" target="bottom" id="navb5"><b><img src="icons/hobbies.svg" height="30%" width="30%" title="Hobbies" class="invert"></b></a></font>
        </font>
    </nav>
        <div align="left" style="margin-top: -5%; color: #eb4979;">
            <img src="images/logo.png" height="40%">
            <font size="10%"><b><span style=" position: absolute; margin-top: 10; text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)">Dexter Silva</span></b></font>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't upload images or images src is worg

Comment: i uploaded the images. wdym by the image src? its located properly

Comment: can you post your code, so we can see what went wrong

Comment: its a big file so i put the code that is one of the broken ones

Comment: Infinityfree free tier has this kind of problems.Once I used it for a school project and had lot of difficulties especially sending data from a GSM module to hosted page.Use Heroku.

Comment: i have used two free domains and still has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

please check that all your files are uploaded... for instance i cannot find

```
<img src="images/logo.png" height="40%">
```

images/logo.png on your server.

also **icons/favorites.png** should be in **images/icons/favorites.png** 
so it cannot find the pictures.

Some servers are Case sensitive so make sure your html finds it

nice work by the way, keep trying
hint: your menu buttons open new pages. Better show your content in the same page
try something like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try that, BTW my teacher wont let us use jquery and css but i insisted to use css since html without css looks disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

You images are in a nested folder, add `images/` 
to the path to link to the correct folder:
`src="images/icons/favorites.png"`
instead of 
`src="icons/favorites.png"`

Comment: i already did that in the first place cause i was making it from html scratch